# create download link for php created image

Tags: php, download

I am working on a little resize and download image kind of php script wherein the events must happen in the following fashion :

1. A visitor uploads an image file.
2. The image is resized by the script.
3. A download link to the resized image appears in the front-end.

My resizing code is ready and working but I need help with the third part, that is how do I offer a download link to the recently created image. Here is a gist of how the resized image is created i the php script.

```
<?php  
       //normal validation stuff happens here
       //resizing stuff happens here

    //here is last part of the code that creates the resized image

    $filename = uniqid();
    $file = 'uploads/'.$filename.'.jpeg';   
    imagejpeg($new, $file, 80); 
    imagedestroy($new);
```

This **download link must prompt as a download box** instead of opening a new tab. `Headers` is what I know is needed in case we need to offer a download link. But this is useless to me unless I understand a right approach to this. Also please understand that my situation may be a little different as this is not a download link for a static-resource. Here the images to be downloaded are created dynamically at every request, everytime.

While I am struggling on my own a solution, will be great otherwise please provide me a road-map of what steps should be taken or what are functions that I will need to get this done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `download link must prompt as a download box` -- What is a *download box*? Could you clarify?

Comment: The pop-up modal-box prompted by the browser on clicking the download link which has the options of open with..... and save as ...Sorry I dont know the right term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 - User is uploading picture and you are saving it on server (you can resize it now) with new unique name (maybe md5 from time()?). On response page you can give link like this `www.mypage.com/downloadimg.php?fileid=54gj6hg45h654g` where last part is generated file name.

Step 2 - User clicks download link. You just have to send headers from Hanky 웃 Panky answer and then `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a download using proper headers.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Comment: @HankyPanky Yes, this goes to the end of my script and how and what link do I show at the template-page ?